# Soft-trigger HW-Interrupt, Linux Kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, interrupt

I'm writing SW for a foot-controller. For implementing a heartbeat-functionality, ideally spanning as much of the system 'stack' as possible I'm trying to figure out how to simulate a button-press, calling the GPIO-associated ISR directly if possible. Following Derek Molloy's [tutorial](http://derekmolloy.ie/kernel-gpio-programming-buttons-and-leds/), my user-space component calls via blocking read into the LKM, receiving the button-nr. pressed:

```
static DECLARE_WAIT_QUEUE_HEAD(wq);
static uint8_t switch_pressed_flag = 0;
static uint8_t heartbeat_const = 20;


static ssize_t dev_read(struct file *filep, char *buffer, size_t len, loff_t *offset) // called whenever device is being read from user space
{
   wait_event_interruptible(wq, switch_pressed_flag != 0);  
   switch_pressed_flag = 0;
   copy_to_user(buffer, msg_lkm_to_user, sizeof(msg_lkm_to_user));

   return 0;                                                             
}
```

So read is on the wait-queue until the interrupt occurs:

```
static irq_handler_t fc_irq_handler(unsigned int irq, void *dev_id, struct pt_regs *regs)
{
   uint8_t button_nr = *(uint8_t*)dev_id;
  
   tm_cur = jiffies_to_msecs(jiffies); // debounce
   if ( (tm_cur - tm_last[button_nr]) > 300 )
   {   
       msg_lkm_to_user[0] = button_nr; 
       
       switch_pressed_flag = 1;
       wake_up_interruptible(&wq);
    } 

   tm_last[button_nr] = tm_cur;
  
   return (irq_handler_t) IRQ_HANDLED;      // Announce that the IRQ has been handled correctly
}
```

For the heartbeat a thread is spanned that should trigger the ISR every second or so:

```
static int heartbeat(void* arg)
{
    while(!kthread_should_stop())
    {
        set_current_state(TASK_RUNNING);
    
        fc_irq_handler(0, (void*)&heartbeat_const, NULL);  // 'manual' call, arbitrary button number
    
        set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
        msleep(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What I'm seeing is the manual ISR calls don't wake the read/user thread, getting somehow queued up until a real HW interrupt occurs.

I considered thread context might be a factor, but ISRs also have different context. Any ideas?

Comment: Whenever `wake_up_interruptible` is called, waiting thread is awoken. Of course, if you have single core then awoken thread won't be executed until caller enables interrupts. Note, that you have racy period between `wait_event_interruptible` and clearing *switch_pressed_flag*: If `fc_irq_handler` sets the flag during this time, this setting will be lost.

Comment: The *switch_pressed_flag* is only used as a wake-up condition. With HW-interrupts, the code works fine.

Comment: Probably, `wake_up_interruptible()` is not called with ISR for some reason.